# Jquery if value <= something dont working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help me please to understand why not working that part of code.
I'm trying to style a block depending on a variable, but that part doesn't work.

```
var starsrating = 3;

    function markstars() {

        if (jQuery(starsrating).val() >= 1) {
            jQuery("div.rating-star1").addClass("rating-star-active");
             console.log("1");
        }
        if  (jQuery(starsrating).val() >= 2) {
            jQuery("div.rating-star1, div.rating-star2").addClass("rating-star-active");
             console.log("2");
        }
        if  (jQuery(starsrating).val() >= 3) {
            jQuery("div.rating-star1, div.rating-star2, div.rating-star3").addClass("rating-star-active");
             console.log("3");
        }
        if  (jQuery(starsrating).val() >= 4) {
            jQuery("div.rating-star1, div.rating-star2, div.rating-star3, div.rating-star4").addClass("rating-star-active");
             console.log("4");
        }
        if  (jQuery(starsrating).val() >= 5) {
            jQuery("div.rating-star1, div.rating-star2, div.rating-star3, div.rating-star4, div.rating-star5").addClass("rating-star-active");
             console.log("5");
        }
        console.log("end of func");
    }
     markstars();
```

Comment: `starsrating` is already a number, you don't need to wrap it with jQuery. jQuery is for manipulating DOM elements. Just do `starsrating >= 1`. Also, show us your HTML.

Comment: [Relevant SO meme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`starsrating` is a plain number; you can't call `jQuery` on it.

A further simplification is to loop over all numbers 1..5 and set the states of the `div`s programmatically:

```
function markstars(starsrating) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    jQuery("div.rating-star" + i).toggleClass("rating-star-active", starsrating >= i);
  }
}
markstars(3);
```